# Convert String date YYYY-MM to date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a date as a String like : `2015-12` for december 2015.

I would like to convert this date to get this date in milliseconds in javascript. (From the first day of the month)

How can i do it ?

Comment: Well, you got the javascript part right. Next step is to write some ;)

Comment: [Here's a google search using your own words, by the way](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=convert%20this%20date%20to%20get%20this%20date%20in%20milliseconds%20in%20javascript)

Answer (score -3):

Try using [the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (`new Date()`).

Answer (score -3):

You could do :

```
YourDate + "-01"
```

And then try to convert to a date

```
d = new Date(YourDate)
```

And finaly :

```
d.getMilliseconds()
```